# Removing white text artifacts from medical images with TensorFlow results in black images

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, computer-vision, medical-imaging

I am working with a dataset of medical CT and MRI scan images that have white text artifacts (patient information) printed on them. I want to remove these artifacts using TensorFlow. My approach is to threshold the images to identify the artifacts and then apply a mask to remove them.

[This is a sample CT scan image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a99cS.jpg)

However, it didn't work, I want to know is there a commonly used method or a model for such applications?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What are your steps and the model you are using as base?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.